# Що означає слово "крафтовий"?

Tags: значення-слів, прикметники

Дедалі частіше чую вживання слів "крафтовий/крафтова", але не розумію що воно означає.

Наприклад, крафтовий сир, крафтова пекарня, крафтове пиво.

[Неофіційне джерело про крафтовий сир](https://cheesemandry.com/craftcheese/)

> Що ж то за такий солодкий крафт? Ми більше любимо замінювати це слово
> рідним українським – ремісничий. Від слова ремесло. А що таке ремесло?
> Ремесло – це дрібне, невеличке виробництво, яке базується на ручній
> праці.

Тобто, можна сказати ремісничий сир, ремісниче пиво, реміснича пекарня. Якось дивно звучить. Офіційних джерел не знайшла.

Що означає "крафтовий"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Слово "крафтовий" є запозиченим з англійської. Там це слово у контексті пивоваріння означає пиво виготовлене малими партіями незалежними пивоварами (на відміну від пива виготовленого відомими брендами великими партіями). Джерело: https://www.brewersassociation.org/statistics/craft-brewer-defined/

Я думаю, найближчий за сенсом український відповідник - словосполучення "власного виробництва". Заклади харчування можуть пропонувати своїм клієнтам *випічку власного виробництва* чи *пиво власного виробництва*.

Comment: Частково погоджуюся, але лише частково. _Крафтовий_, на мою думку, перш за все позначає не _власне_ виробництво, а _дрібне_ виробництво (без використання технологій, характерних для масового промислового  виробництва). Наприклад, якщо заклад харчування, що є частиною великого промислового концерну, подає випічку, вироблену цим концерном — то це _власне_ виробництво, але не _крафтове_; а якщо заклад харчування перепродає випічку, яку роблять і продають бабусі з сусіднього села, то це _крафтове_ виробництво, але (з перспективи цього закладу харчування) не _власне_.

Comment: На мою думку, Ваш приклад не зовсім коректний. З перспективи бабусі її випічка - власного виробництва. Перспектива закладу харчування у цьому випадку не є показовою, бо придбаний товар не перестав бути крафтовим тільки від того, що його було придбано через посередника.

Comment: Я не думаю, що якась перспектива є більш показова за інші; а що принаймні з якихось перспектив крафтовий — не те саме, що власного виробництва, то отже загалом крафтовий крафтовий — не те саме, що власного виробництва.

Comment: Я з Вами погоджуюся. Окремі слова в окремих випадках можуть бути тотожними до інших слів, а в інших випадках - можуть не бути. У контексті заданого питання я зрозумію, що може означати "дрібне виробництво". Тим не менш, я раніше не бачив це словосполучення було вжите у значенні "крафтовий". А "власного виробництва" бачив, тому й навів його як приклад. Я визнаю, що у деяких випадках "дрібне" чи "малотиражне" можуть бути доцільнішими, але асоціації зі словом "крафтовий" у мене ці слова не викликають.

Answer (score 5):

Повністю погоджуюся з відповіддю користувача Dmytro Kyrychuk. Але ще хочу додати, що [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kraftovyi) пропонує варіанти "ремісничий", "саморобний", "рукодільний" та "ручної роботи". Хочу звернути вашу увагу саме на останнє слово, бо крафтовими можуть бути не лише їжа та напої, але й, наприклад "крафтовий одяг", "крафтова сумка" і саме тут "крафтовий" можна замінити на "ручної роботи".

Comment: Варіант "ручної роботи" не видається найкращим через нелаконічність і складність утворення похідних слів.